# MongoDB: find elements where element id is in array of ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working with a collection of users like so

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc822c6547b8500340b2c34"), 
    "firstName" : "SomeFirstName", 
    "lastName" : "SomeLastName", 
    "uniqueId" : "HF2134fGA"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("b80340b2c34522c65450dc87"), 
    "firstName" : "AnotherFirstName", 
    "lastName" : "AnotherLastName", 
    "uniqueId" : "4F21fGH3A"
}
```

Also a list of Object like so

```
[{name: "Name", id:"4F21fGH3A"}, {name: "Name", id:"21fG34HFA"}]
```

I would like to return every documents where an id contained in the objects array matches a uniqueId in the collection of users.

Answer (score 0):

The [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator and a map to remove the unwanted elements on the server seems to do the trick

```
{ "uniqueId": {$in: ["4F21fGH3A", "21fG34HFA"]} }
```